# C# - Difference between Automatic Property and returning a backing field?

Tags: c#, field, automatic-properties

Simple question I imagine, but what is the difference between these lines of code:

Code 1

```
public int Temp { get; set; }
```

and

Code 2

```
private int temp;
public int Temp { get { return temp; } }
```

My understand was that an automatic property as per Code 1 would perform the exact same function as Code 2?

I'm reading Head First C# and I'm finding it hard to understand why it's using two different ways of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primary difference between your Code1 and Code2 is that in #1, the property is settable.

You can achieve the same thing using automatic properties, because the setter can be private:

```
public int Temp { get; private set; }
```

Automatic properties was added in C#3, and is really just syntactic sugar for the longer version using a field. If you don't need to access the field directly, there is no reason not to use automatic properties. Automatic properties are equivalent to using a field - the compiler generates the field for you, it is just not accessible in code.

Comment: I see, so trying to set this property just results in it returning the backing field instead?

Comment: Yes, the auto property creates a field but you do not have to clutter your code with it and the "private set" makes sure no external usage can change the field.

Comment: I think I might be being a bit thick here, but why would you want to return a value when you're in fact trying to assign to it? So if I was using code 2 and I used "Temp = 2" somewhere, where does that return value go?

Comment: @t84, no, the setter never returns anything (you can use it to set from within the class when it is private. It cannot be set from outside the class - if you try to do so, you will get a compile error).

Comment: Aha, something just clicked, thanks :) I was getting confused and thinking "return temp" was part of the 'set' where in fact it's just an addition to the 'get'.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is a writable property.

It's equivalent to

```
private int temp;
public int Temp { 
    get { return temp; } 
    set { temp = value; }
}
```

(except that you can't use the backingfield directly), but it requires 1 line of code instead of five.
When writing classes with 5 or 6 simple properties, auto-properties can make the classes much shorter.

You can make read-only auto-properties by writing

```
public int Temp { get; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The "automagic" property is just a "short-hand" notation:

```
public int Temp { get; set; }
```

is just a lot simpler to type than

```
public int Temp 
{   
   get { return _temp; }
   set { _temp = value; } 
}
```

but functionally equivalent. Just a nice "shorthand" to improve your productivity, but no additional or magic functionality, really.

Answer (score 1):

If your second example had both a getter and a setter, they would be functionally equivalent.

As it stands now, the first is publicly gett-able but can't be set publicly. You could also achieve the same thing using auto properties:

```
public int Temp { get; private set; }
```

And in case you're curious, automatic properties still get a backing private field. That bit is just handled by the compiler for you so that life is easier.

Answer (score 0):

As for the reason why I would use property with a backing field is when I want to do something else when getting or setting the property.  For example, a validation routine embedded into the property itself, or caching, etc...

Otherwise, for simple get and set, I'd use the automatic property format.  It's more compact and involves less coding which I think it's a good thing.